# Variables on heap and stack

Tags: c, variables, heap-memory, stack-memory

I've been trying to look for the answer to this question, but its a little tricky to me.

So it goes!

```
    int square(int* a){
      return (*a)*(*a)
    }


    int main(){
      int b = 20;  
      square(&b);
    }
```

My question is: Where are stored variables a and b?

In my opinion variable b is stored in stack but i have some questions regarding a.

When you call square(&b) you're passing the reference, in this case de address of variable b in the stack.

Then, function square(int* a) receives a (int* a) argument which means that it will receive a pointer which in this case is the reference for variable b in the stack. So the value for variable a will be the address of the variable b. But both will be stored in stack. I am pretty sure that's on the stack, but...Or will b in the stack and a in the heap? Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `b` will be on the stack.

When `square` is called, `a` and `&b` are the same value. Depending on the calling convention and compiler optimizations, this value may be in a register, or on the stack, or both.

Comment: So ...what case could be that so a would be stored in the heap?None?

Comment: You use `malloc` (or `calloc`) to allocate data on the heap and retrieve a pointer to that data.  In C, that's the only way something ends up on the heap.

Comment: Ok, but to be more specific, what variable would be on the heap?It would never be the `a` or `b` variables right?Those are always on the stack,  right? Maybe `*a` or a `*b` with malloc would be on the heap, but at the same time wouldn't they be on the stack?

Comment: If you use `void *a = malloc(...)` then the memory allocated `*a` is in the heap, but `a` will be in a register or on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! `b` will be pushed onto the stack, and `a` is just a pointer to `b`, so the reference of `b` and the value held by the pointer `a` are the same value, which is the stack location of `b`. However, the pointer `'a'` will not stay on the stack after the function is called-- it will go out of scope, but `'b'` will still be on the stack after the function is called, though its value will be changed.